# What are «Structures»?

Tags: structure, best-practice

I wonder what structures are since everybody writes about it here. But I can only finde one tiny sentence in the official docs:

> «Used when entries do have an inherent relationship with each other,
>   unlike Channels. They are both sortable and hierarchical.»

Is there somewhere a bit more of a real world explenation/example on when/why/how to use this «structure» thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A structure is a section that allows for a 'tree' like layout with hierarchy. A good example of where Structures might be used for instance is the Craft documentation pages, or building a navigation using a section.